# Translation Golf L - All those moments will be lost in time, like tears in rain

Tags: traducción, translation-golf, inglés

Welcome to a new edition of the game! If this is your first time, there's some info for beginners at the end of this post.

I didn't expect to have the honor of choosing the new question, so, for this edition I will select one famous monologue that I like, from the Science fiction movie "Blade Runner". From the movie ([Youtube link directly to that moment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NoAzpa1x7jU&t=100)):

> I've seen things you people wouldn't believe. Attack ships on fire off the shoulder of Orion. I watched C-beams glitter in the dark near the Tannhäuser Gate. All those moments will be lost in time, like tears in rain. Time to die.
>
> <sub>(180 characters.)</sub>

The goal is to translate the given text to Spanish, using as few letters as possible, while keeping all the original text's meaning and concepts more or less intact.

As an initial point, the Wikipedia translation, (removing wrong translations to the original Spanish dub) says:

> Yo he visto cosas que ustedes no creerían. Naves de ataque en llamas más   allá de Orión. He visto rayos-C brillar en la oscuridad cerca de la Puerta   de Tannhäuser. Todos esos momentos se perderán en el tiempo, como lágrimas   en la lluvia. Es hora de morir.
>
>   <sub>(201 characters.)</sub>

- Rules: [Translation-golf rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2591/this-is-translation-golf-the-translation-with-the-least-number-of-characters-wi/2592#2592)
- Letter counter: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/)

[EDIT] (Thanks for the remark, @walen)

In order to have a valid answer, all the concepts must be on there:

- The "I saw things you won't believe".
- Each of the concepts named there: Attack ships and C-rays.
- A metaphor with all will be gone.
- The statement to die.

[/EDIT]

You may want to check past translation-golf questions to get a feel of the game dynamics and the kind of answers expected.

Want to share translation ideas, ask for clarifications or just tease other contesters? Join us in [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-), Spanish.SE's official chat room!

Have fun!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**79**

> <s>Lo increíble visto —arder naves en Orion, rayos-C.en Tannhäuser—, llanto en la lluvia, ido será. Muero.</s>

---

[if having to add the gate concept], here are two proposed rewrites:

85

> Lo increible que vi: igneas naves en Orion, rayos-C a la boca de Tannhäuser. Gotas de un tiempo ido son. Muero.

**83** (mejor)

> Asombros que vi (igneas naves en Orion, rayos-C a la boca de Tannhäuser) idos, cual gotas del tiempo. Muero.

Comment: Hum... no creo que sea una respuesta válida: no veo que hables del "He visto cosas que vosotros no creeríais".

Comment: Cierto, gracias @Chococroc, ahí modifiqué

Comment: Mejor, :D. Por cierto, "Yo, todo acaba" lo podrías poner como "Acabo", o "Muero". Y otra apreciación: No veo la metáfora de "Todo se perderá, como lágrimas en la lluvia", ¿está indicada y no la veo?

Comment: ¡Wow! ¡muy buena respuesta! ¿No debería "Muero" ir al final de la frase para seguir con la coherencia del original?

Comment: @Chococroc ¿no debería mantenerse el concepto de la "puerta" de Tannhäuser?

Comment: @user2325442, tienen razón, falta indicar la puerta de alguna manera

Comment: ¿Por qué? No esta consignado entre los requisitos explícitos del planteo ( En donde enumeras:  `The "I saw things you won't believe"; Each of the concepts named there: Attack ships and C-rays.;  A metaphor with all will be gone; The statement to die`

Comment: @Charlie, modifiqué con dos versiones que quizás completen ese requisito extra

Comment: @user2325442, ¡Felicidades! Me ha encantado el trabajo que has montado. La de Charlie está más divertida, pero esta está muy bien. Te corresponde poner el siguiente, Golf ;).

Answer (score 6):

#### <s>105 95</s> 86 caracteres

> [Fliparías](https://dle.rae.es/?w=flipar&m=form). Vi [fragatas](https://dle.rae.es/?w=fragata&m=form) arder en Orión, rayos-C [rielar](https://dle.rae.es/?w=rielar&m=form) en el [uzo](https://dle.rae.es/?w=uzo&m=form) de Tannhäuser: ríos diluidos en el mar. [Palmo](https://dle.rae.es/?w=palmar&m=form).

Comment: ¿Fragatas en el espacio? ¿Qué es esto, el Capitán Harlock? XD

Comment: En Star Wars hay fragatas y corbetas.

Comment: Solo era una broma. Y por si había dudas había puesto el equisdé

Comment: Guapísimo, :D, pero para mantener el flujo del "Flipa" molaría un "Palmo" en vez de "Me voy", XD.

Answer (score 5):

#### 24,167

> *He visto cosas que no creeríais. TGs en llamas más allá del calentómetro de SO. Siete preguntas al día brillando en la oscuridad del Área 51. Todos esos momentos se perderán en el tiempo, cual medallas de Nice Answer cayendo sobre una cuenta borrada. Hora de morir.*